# FullTIK successor of 2014

Tags: user-interface, fltk

i used to program my GUI, long long times ago, using FLTK, under Linux. 
This library is pretty awsome, but a bit vintage for a modern application.
I'm asking to you, which might be a choice of library, any kind of, for modern GUIs based on C/C++? Under Linux... in other words, which is a worthy successor of FLTK, in 2014 style?

Thanks very much

Comment: From the [help] *Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic*

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that you can have themes in FLTK? However, there is no native L&F (FLTK design decision - native L&F would just make the library bigger).